# What is the domain of these two graphs?

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding the domain of these two graphs and whether or not the black dots make a difference or not.I drew a picture to illustrate my dilemma since I am not sure if the domain of graph 2 is same as graph 1 or if its all real numbers. How does the dot effect the domain?

[image]

Comment: The answer you gave is correct for #1.  It appears that the answer to #2 would be $-4<x<4$.

Comment: My book seems to give the domain for #2 with a greater than or equal sign.

Comment: It looks like there are closed circles at the endpoints of graph #1, in which case your domain for graph #1 is correct.  Are there open circles at the endpoints of graph #2?

Comment: There are no circles, nothing at all it just ends like that...

Comment: graph #2 is straight from my calculus book.

Comment: Does your calculus book use arrows at the endpoints of other graphs?

Comment: none of that, i copied it straight from book. No arrows, no dots, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Closed circles at the endpoints indicate that the endpoints are included.  Thus, the domain for the first graph is

$$[-4, 4] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}|~-4 \leq x \leq 4\}$$

Open circles at the endpoints indicate that the endpoints are not included.  If that is what the author intended, then the domain of the second graph is

$$(-4, 4) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}|~-4 < x < 4\}$$

Arrows at the endpoints indicate that the graph continues beyond what is depicted in the graph, in which case the domain would be the set of all real numbers

$$\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, \infty)$$

To distinguish between the second and third possibilities, you should carefully read the examples and other exercises to see whether the author uses arrows at the ends of other graphs to indicate that the graph continues beyond what is depicted in the graph or open circles to indicate that the endpoints have been omitted.